# How to speed up grep on large history?

Tags: grep, zsh, performance, command-history

I have an unlimited `.zsh_history` which is currently at 10k lines. I often want to see all commands from history that have a certain string, for example `curl`. If I do `history | grep curl` it takes a long time to finish. If I do `grep curl ~/.zsh_history` it is much faster, but the formatting is broken (timestamps aren't parsed into dates, delimiters are left as symbols).

Is there a way around the slowness of piping `history` to `grep`? I see people recommending Ctrl+R but that is clearly not the same thing - grep produces a **list** of commands while Ctrl+R shows them one at a time. Also piping to grep allows chaining multiple grep filters, while the same thing is not possible with Ctrl+R.

Comment: I can grep 16000 lines (1MB) in 0.030 secs. Grep is not your problem. Where you say "timestamps aren't parsed into dates, delimiters are left as symbols" strongly hints that the `history` command is doing a lot of processing. So some technique that does that conversion incrementally one-time, or in background, is going to be helpful.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Correct, in fact the problem is still there if I just do `history` without `grep` (although `grep` proves that the problem is not only due to the large number of lines printed to stdout)

Answer (score 1):

First, if you aren't doing anything more complex than grep, limiting matches with `history -m PATTERN` may be faster than grep. Even if you're applying complex filters afterwards, try adding a simple filter with `-m` that gets rid of most undesired lines.

If the limiting factor is the time spent printing out the full history with `history`, there's a hackish way to print the part of the history selected by grep (or other filter). Use [`fc -p`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-fc) to start a new history, and make it read the selected part of the history. Untested:

```
function format_history {
  fc -p -a =(cat)
  fc -l 1
}
history 1 | grep curl | format_history
```

This isn't very convenient to use (you need something on both sides of the pipeline, so you can't just have a `magic_history_filter` prefix). And what speed it gains in not formatting the whole history, it might lose in having fancier plumbing and requiring the use of a temporary file (zsh can only read the history from a seekable file, not from a pipe).

Comment: So is `history -m curl` supposed to return all lines containing `curl`? I get `omz_history:fc:13: no matching events found`.

Comment: @Donentolon It has to be `history -m 'curl*' 1`. Not very convenient to type, for sure. This is with the `history` builtin, I don't know about `omz_history`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple function that will let you quickly search your entire history for any string:

```bsh
histgrep() {
  fc -lm "*${1}*" 1 -1
}
```

or even faster:

```bsh
histgrep() {
  zmodload -i zsh/parameter
  print -raC2 ${(kv)history[(R)*$1*]}
}
```

Either of these outputs a history line number in front of each line, so you can execute the line you want with `!<number>`. For example to insert history line number 2596 into your command line, do

```bsh
!2596
```

then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I have around 3400 lines of history. Doing `histgrep cd` produces over 220 lines for me but takes only about 0.004 seconds to complete with the first version of the function and half that with the second version.

Comment: There's also the `print -rC1 -- ${(M)history:#*pattern*}` if you don't care about timestamps

Comment: `fc -l` does not output timestamps; it outputs history line numbers, so you can execute the line you want with `!<number>`.

Comment: OK, so maybe rather `print -raC2 ${(kv)history[(R)*pattern*]}` if you want the history numbers

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and it's twice as fast as my solution —but it's also twice as hard to read.  Plus, you might also need to do `zmodload -i zsh/parameter` first for that to work, depending on your Zsh installation.

Comment: These days, `zsh/parameter` should automatically be loaded upon the first reference to `$history` (or any special variable provided by the module).

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks for your contribution! I added it to my answer.

Answer (score -2):

From time to time you can run `history >~/.zsh_history.cache`. Then you can grep over that file plus the output of `history` for those commands missing in that file.

I am not familiar with `zsh` and thus cannot provide code for combining the file content with the command output.

Answer (score -2):

You could try ripgrep ( https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep )
Is actually faster and has many useful filtering options: the github page has a long list of features.

It's in the repositories of many distributions.

Comment: It may help a little, but if `history | grep` is noticeable slower than `grep ~/.zsh_history`, the performance bottleneck is not grep.

Comment: appreciate the suggestion, but `grep` is not the bottleneck here, `history` is.